# Beginner String Manipulation

Tags: java

Why does the following code not work for the question here? http://codingbat.com/prob/p101475

```
public String frontTimes(String str, int n) {
  if (str.length() < 3) {
     String front = str;
  } else {
     String front = str.substring(0, 3);
  }
  String copies = "";

  while (n > 0) {
     copies = copies + front; 
     n = n - 1;
  }

  return copies;


}
```

I really don't understand the "front cannot be resolved" error I'm getting

Comment: because you define `String front ... ` inside of the `if` statement, Java will destroy it as soon as it leaves that block of code. All you need to do is put `String front = "";` on a line before the `if`.

Answer (score 3):

The scope of your variable `front` is only within the `if`/`else` block. You might want to try declaring the variable `front` before the `if`, and then assigning within the `if`.

Answer (score 1):

The [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) of variables in Java is limited to the set of curly brackets in which the variable was declared.

If you declare a variable like this:

```
if (str.length() < 3) {
    String front = str;
}
```

then `front` only exists within the curly brackets of the `if` block.

When you do this:

```
else {
   String front = str.substring(0, 3);
}
```

then another variable, also called `front`, exists within the curly brackets of your `else` block.

However, if you declare the variable before the `if` block:

```
String front;
if (str.length() < 3) {
    front = str;
} else {
    front = str.substring(0, 3);
}
```

then it is in scope for the whole method (because that is the surrounding set of curly brackets).

Alternatively, you could simplify your variable initialisation using the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:):

```
String front = (str.length() < 3 ? str : str.substring(0, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `front` as a local variable of your `if` block and then as (another) local variable of your `else` clause. You must declare it in the scope of the method block.

```
public String frontTimes(String str, int n) {
  String front;
  if (str.length() < 3)
      front = str;
  else 
      front = str.substring(0,3);
  // or shorter, with a ternary 
  // String front = str.length() < 3 ? str : str.substring(0, 3);

  String copies = "";
  while (n > 0) {
     copies = copies + front; 
     n = n - 1;
  }
  return copies;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is scoping rules. A field like `String front` is only visible inside the `{ }` it is defined.

I suggest you try getting the code to compile in an IDE first as this will help you with these error.

You might find this solution interesting. It iterates O(log N) times instead of O(N) times. (I suspect it's not better, but a different way to divide up the problem)

```
public String frontTimes(String str, int n) {
  if (str.length() > 3) str = str.substring(0, 3);
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder(str);
  while (n > 0) {
     if ((n & 1) == 1)
        sb.append(sb2);
     n /= 2;
     sb2.append(sb2);
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
public String frontTimes(String str, int n) {

  String front;

  if (str.length() < 3) {
     front = str;
  } 

  else {
     front = str.substring(0, 3);
  }

  String copies = "";

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    copies += front;
  }

  return copies; 

}
```